# GWT Using DoubleClickHandler and ClickHandler for the particular element

Tags: java, gwt

I've an element with both `onClick` and `onDoubleClick` handlers. I need to call different methods for each, but I'm not able to do that.

Is there any way available?

**Code:**

```
docksWidget.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {                        
    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Window.alert("Single Click");
    }
});
docksWidget.addDoubleClickHandler(new DoubleClickHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onDoubleClick(DoubleClickEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Window.alert("Double Click");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code, the `ClickHandler` and the `DoubleClickHandler` will both be fired on a double click. You will need to differentiate the "single click" and "the first click of a double click". Below is the code you can consider which adds a timer to `ClickHandler` to detect if it's the "single click" or "the first click of a double click".

```
final int[] clicks = {0}; //we need to make this final because it's used in lambda

testAnchor.addClickHandler(event -> {
    clicks[0]++;
    Scheduler.get().scheduleFixedPeriod(() ->
    {
        if (clicks[0] == 1)
        {
            //put your single click action here
            Window.alert("single click");
        }
        clicks[0] = 0;
        return false;
    }, 500); //The default double click timeframe in Microsoft Windows is 500ms
});
testAnchor.addDoubleClickHandler(event -> { 
    //put your double click action here
    Window.alert("double click");
});
```